# Android ListAdapter is not updating

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, listadapter

I have a `ListAdapter` which is used to display a list in the `Listview`. Now I have added a longpress menu action for delete any selected item.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        final Long wordId = menuInfo.id;
        // selected_row = menuInfo.position;

        // To get the id of the clicked item in the list use menuInfo.id
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CONTEXT_DELETE:
            deleteRes(wordId);  // delete function for the item
            break;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        }
        //((BaseAdapter) favAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
```

But after deletion the list is updating and showing the old list with deleted item. I tried using `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but it is not working. What is the solution of the prob?

Comment: Are you sure the underlying data is deleted thru `deleteRes(wordId);`?

Comment: data is deleting properly...if i go to another section....and come back to that section...it is giving proper list.

Comment: Maybe you can post more codes, like the adapter, to see what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following code and the problem is solved.

```
favCursor  = wordDataHelper.getCursorFav();
((SimpleCursorAdapter) favAdapter).changeCursor(favCursor);
```

Comment: Please elaborate how did you solve this? I am having same issue. I have posted my code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512776/listview-not-upadated-properly-after-deletion-in-android-fragment . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

delete the item from array/list, after that assign the array/list to adapter and after that write notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: There is no array or list. It is a Cursor, that is supplied to the favAdapter(which is a ListAdapter) using "ListAdapter favAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,favCursor,new String[] {WordDataHelper.ENGWORD},new int[] {android.R.id.text1});"

Answer (score 0):

After you deleted the item from the list you have to get a new Cursor by doing a new query on the database. You can then change the cursor of your SimpleCursorAdapter ([CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)) by calling [changeCursor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) with the new cursor as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

use getListView().invalidateViews after deletion.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the item from your database with a query
2. Either get a new cursor, or requery the old one `adapter.getCursor().requery()`
3. Call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged`

Comment: I think requery() is deprecated.

Comment: So it is. Never used it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try using notifyDataSetChanged method, it should work.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But, sometimes it fails. If it fails for you, then reinitialize the adepter with the new list elements. It works for me.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```